# Como exibir corretamente um XML que tenha células em branco em PHP?

Tags: php, html, xml, php-domdocument

Boa tarde pessoal.

Segui uma [vídeo aula](https://youtu.be/7-5yUgiOAo8) de como exibir dados de XML em PHP, e deu tudo certo, o resultado foi exibido corretamente, porém se uma célula estiver em branco ele joga o valor da próxima célula na variável, e isso está impedindo que eu utilize como pretendo.

Esse é o index, não tem segredo nele:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Importar dados do Excel</title>
 <head>
 <body>
  <h1>Upload Excel</h1>
  
  <form method="POST" action="processa.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <label>Arquivo</label>
   <input type="file" name="arquivo"><br><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
  </form>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

E aqui é onde o XML é processado e o resultado exibido na tela:

```
<?php
//$dados = $_FILES['arquivo'];
//var_dump($dados);

if(!empty($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'])){
    $arquivo = new DomDocument();
    $arquivo->load($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name']);
    //var_dump($arquivo);

    $linhas = $arquivo->getElementsByTagName("Row");
    //var_dump($linhas);

    $primeira_linha = true;

    foreach($linhas as $linha){
        if($primeira_linha == false){
            $nome = $linha->getElementsByTagName("Data")->item(0)->nodeValue;
            echo "Nome: $nome <br>";

            $email = $linha->getElementsByTagName("Data")->item(1)->nodeValue;
            echo "E-mail: $email <br>";

            $niveis_acesso_id = $linha->getElementsByTagName("Data")->item(2)->nodeValue;
            echo "Nivel de Acesso: $niveis_acesso_id <br>";

            echo "<hr>";
        }
        $primeira_linha = false;
    }
}
?>
```

Essa é a tabela gerada com o XML:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E o resultado amostrado na página quando o XML é carregado é esse:

> Nome: Cesar
>   E-mail: cesar@celke.com.br
>   Nivel de Acesso: 1
>
> Nome: Kelly
>   E-mail: kelly@celke.com.br
>   Nivel de Acesso: 1
>
> Nome: Jessica 
>   E-mail: Jessica@celke.com.br
>   Nivel de Acesso: 2

Porém, se eu ir na planilha e simplesmente remover algum E-mail por exemplo, ele empurra o valor que seria do nível de acesso para a variável, deixando a visualização dos dados desse jeito:

> Nome: Cesar
>   E-mail: 1
>
> **Notice**: Trying to get property 'nodeValue' of non-object in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\Somente_importar_excel\processa.php** on line **23**
>
> Nivel de Acesso:
>
> Nome: Kelly
>   E-mail: kelly@celke.com.br
>   Nivel de Acesso: 1
>
> Nome: Jessica
>   E-mail: Jessica@celke.com.br
>   Nivel de Acesso: 2

Não sei se expliquei bem a minha dúvida, mas se alguém puder me dar uma luz de como posso tratar quando a célula estiver em branco...

Comment: Já tentou um 
`if($niveis_acesso_id == '' || $niveis_acesso_id == null){
$niveis_acesso_id = "não tem";
}`

Comment: Vinicius, não cheguei à tentar isso pois por via das dúvidas dei um echo nas variáveis, e elas estão recebendo valores errados caso haja uma célula vazia. Basicamente a variável $email  recebe o que deveria ir para a $niveis_acesso_id caso a célula do email esteja vazia.

Answer (score -1):

Bruno,
Tive a mesma dúvida que a sua, mas não obtive sucesso em solucionar. Estou com uma tarefa de importar uma planilha Excel para o sistema (utilizando PHP) e como não achei a solução eu mudei a forma como fazer utilizando este vídeo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2OJfgIRWnmc (How to Import Excel Data into MySQL Database using PHP | PHP Tutorial | PHPEXCEL) . Nesta forma aceita campos em brancos, porém será importação de Excel e não XML.

Em XML (como está na sua pergunta) ele não mostra os campos vazios da planilha importada, ele pega o valor da próxima célula, mas se você abrir o XML no VSCODE o campo em branco estará "sinalizado" assim:

```html
"<Cell ss:Index="5" ss:StyleID="s62" ss:HRef="mailto:teste@email.com"><Data ss:Type="String">teste@email.com</Data></Cell>"
```

Se o elemento tem o atributo "ss:Index", pelas análises feitas, mostra que tem dados nessa célula de index = 5, mas na célula anterior não tem.